# facebook login with swift 3

Tags: swift3, ios8

please help me with Facebook login

I've started with putting into pod

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
and then run pod install
```

after this i've imported this into my viewController

```
import UIKit
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])
    loginButton.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
}

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I updated info.plist with Facebook data

how Do i get user basic profile data once user has authorized  app?
What goes in AppDelegate file?

thanks

Comment: Here is a [tutorial that might help you](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/05/facebook-login-swift-language-ios/) get what you want.

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the code for login the Facebook by a `UIButton` click.

**Step 1**: Copy this code into your class file:

```swift
import UIKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

class Facebook_loginPageViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }


   @IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
      self.facebooklogin()
   }


   func facebooklogin() {
      let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
      fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in

      print("\n\n result: \(result)")
      print("\n\n Error: \(error)")

      if (error == nil) {
        let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
        if(fbloginresult.isCancelled) {
           //Show Cancel alert
        } else if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")) {
            self.returnUserData()
            //fbLoginManager.logOut()
        }
       }
     })
    }


    func returnUserData() {
       let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name"])
       graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
          if ((error) != nil) {
              // Process error
              print("\n\n Error: \(error)")
           } else {
                 let resultDic = result as! NSDictionary
                 print("\n\n  fetched user: \(result)")
                 if (resultDic.value(forKey:"name") != nil) {
                     let userName = resultDic.value(forKey:"name")! as! String as NSString?
                     print("\n User Name is: \(userName)")
                  }

                 if (resultDic.value(forKey:"email") != nil) {
                     let userEmail = resultDic.value(forKey:"email")! as! String as NSString?
                     print("\n User Email is: \(userEmail)")
                  }
             }
        })
     }
}
```

**Step 2**: In `AppDelegate` add the id of Facebook:

```swift
import UIKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let str_URL = url.absoluteString as NSString
        if str_URL.contains("fb1111111111111111")// put you id here {
           return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
                    app,
                    open: url as URL!,
                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
                    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
          }


           return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
                app,
                open: url as URL!,
                sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
                annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        }
}
```

**Updated Code** :App Delegate

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let str_URL = url.absoluteString as NSString
        if str_URL.contains("fb111111111111111"){
           return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
                    app,
                    open: url as URL?,
                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
                    annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
          }


           return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
                app,
                open: url as URL?,
                sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
                annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        }
}
```

**Step 3**: put this code into `info.plist'

```swift
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
     <array>
         <dict>
             <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
             <array>
                 <string>fb1111111111111111</string>
             </array>
         </dict>


     </array>
     <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>2</string>
     <key>FacebookAppID</key>
        <string>1111111111111111</string>
     <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
        <string>Together Deal</string>
     <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbapi</string>
            <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
            <string>fbauth2</string>
            <string>fbshareextension</string>
        </array>
```

Comment: In place of 1111111111111111 add your fb App ID.

Comment: i am getting error after adding this in plist

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code of

**1. ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

import FacebookLogin
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dict : [String : AnyObject]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //creating button
        let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])
        loginButton.center = view.center

        //adding it to view
        view.addSubview(loginButton)

        //if the user is already logged in
        if let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current(){
            getFBUserData()
        }

    }

    //when login button clicked
    @objc func loginButtonClicked() {
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                self.getFBUserData()
            }
        }
    }

    //function is fetching the user data
    func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    self.dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    print(result!)
                    print(self.dict)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**2. AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    //added these 3 methods 
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }


}
```

Source: [**Facebook Login Swift 3 Tutorial**](https://www.simplifiedios.net/facebook-login-swift-3-tutorial/)

Comment: how i can get more than ["fields": "id, name, picture.type(large), email"]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this video be helpfull for you
https://youtu.be/bOS4jqRc8Io

Contents in this Video:

- Facebook SDK integration tutorial with Swift lastest 2018
- Xcode new project setup
- Swift iOS app login with Facebook
- Tutorial Facebook login feature in iOS app
- Add Facebook to Swift iOS app
- Facebook login in iOS app

Steps:

1. Create new simple Swift Xcode project
2. Login to facebook develop page to create the same name APP
3. Add login with Facebook button, login and logout methods
4. Modify the configure plist, create bridging header for C, configure AppDelegate,
5. Run the application and test with simulator

Answer (score 0):

The following are the steps to follow for facebook login in ios app.

```
1.  Create or open an application from Xcode.
2.  Create an application from your facebook account and do required configuration by going through the app settings. 
3.  Install required pods in your project.
4.  Do required configuration in your Appdelegate 
5.  We need to modify plist with your facebook app id that you can get from your app by logging in facebook
6.  Design UI as per your requirement.
```

I have created an article about Facebook login implementation in iOS app using Swift 5 in detail.

You can find clear explanation here [Facebook login using Swift5](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/facebook-login-implementation-ios-app-using-swift-5-nallamsetty)